# Prove $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Let $f$ be a continuous periodic function on $\mathbb{R},$ such that $0 \not\equiv f \geq 0.$
>
> Prove $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}$ diverges.

My thoughts:

I tried applying the Limit Comparison Test with $\frac{1}{x}:$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$$

Continuity and periodicity of $f$ implies $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ does not exist, so I got stuck.

Next I tried the Comparison Test with $\frac{1}{x},$ but couldn't manipulate the inequality to achieve $\frac{1}{x}\leq \frac{f(x)}{x}.$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Let $f$ be $T$-periodic. Integrating by parts, show that iff $f$ has zero-mean, then $F(x) = \int_T^x f(y)dy$ is $T$-periodic and hence $\int_T^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ converges.

Comment: $$\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx\ge \frac{1}{(n+1)}\left(\frac1T\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T}f(t)\,dt\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T > 0$ be a period of $f$, and let $C := \int_0^T f(x)\, dx$. By the assumptions on $f$ we have that $C > 0$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let us compute
$$
\int_1^{1+nT} \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx =
\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{1+(k-1)T}^{1+kT} \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx
\geq \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{1+(k-1)T}^{1+kT} \frac{f(x)}{1+(k-1)T}\, dx
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{C}{1+(k-1)T}.
$$
As $n\to +\infty$, the last term goes to $+\infty$ (since the corresponding series is divergent).

Comment: You missed identifying the crucial assumption that $f$ is positive. Otherwise, your inequality does not hold. Also you need to actually prove why $C>0$.

Comment: Sure. I also forgot to prove that a continuous function on a compact interval is Riemann integrable, and probably many other facts.

Comment: No, to prove the claim means to lay out all the crucial facts showing the effect of each assumption in the problem, which you have not done. Otherwise, why do you not just declare it is "trivially" or "obviously" true and call it a day?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has period $1$ then
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{f(x)}x\,dx=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{f(x)}x\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{f(t+1)}{n+t}\,dt
=\int_0^1 f(t+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+t+1}\,dt$$
and this is a divergent series. With rather more
fiddling around, one can do general period in a similar
fashion.

Comment: The conclusion of divergence is wrong. You are missing the crucial premise that $f$ is nonnegative. An obvious counterexample for your derivation is $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: Also, you have not justified the interchanging of summation and integration. The very fact that the summation is divergent should give you pause. Your derivation would have proved my counterexample above to hold. So your proof is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**hint** 
If $T $ is the period then

$$\int_{nT}^{(n+1)T}\frac {f (x)}{x}dx=\int_0^T\frac {f (t)}{t+nT} dt\ge \frac {1}{(n+1)T} \int_0^Tf(t)dt$$

Comment: You are missing the crucial assumption that $f$ is for otherwise your inequality fails and the conclusion is wrong. For obvious counterexample without the condition, consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Hans Sorry, i used the fact that $f $ is positive.

Comment: My point is that you should make assumption explicit, because there is not really much to say, except this crucial piece of information.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{T > 0}$ the $\ds{\mrm{f}}$-*period*.

With $\ds{R > 0}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{1 + R}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x & =
\int_{1}^{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T + \braces{R/T}T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{1}^{1 + T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{1 + T}^{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T}^{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T + \braces{R/T}T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\int_{1}^{1 + T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{1}^{1 + \braces{R/T}T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x  + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T }\,\dd x} +
\bbox[15px,#ffe]{\ds{\int_{1 + T}^{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}} 
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\bbox[15px,#ffe]{\ds{\int_{1 + T}^{1 + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor - 1}\int_{1 + nT}^{1 + nT + T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor - 1}\int_{1}^{1 + T}{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \over x + nT}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over T}\int_{1}^{1 + T}\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor - 2}{1 \over n + 1 + x/T}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over T}\int_{1}^{1 + T}\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{1 \over n + 1 + x/T} - {1 \over n + \left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor + x/T}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over T}\int_{1}^{1 + T}\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\pars{H_{\left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor + x/T - 1} - H_{x/T}}\,\dd x\qquad
\pars{~\substack{\ds{H_{z}:\ Harmonic}\\ \ds{Number}}~}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{H_{\left\lfloor{R/T}\right\rfloor + x/T - 1} \sim \ln\pars{\left\lfloor{R \over T}\right\rfloor + {x \over T} - 1}\quad\text{as}\quad R \to \infty}$. What do you conclude with the above relations ?.